# My Hosts and corresponding hostvars is given as an JSON input. How to use them in the Playbook

Tags: ansible, hosts, ansible-inventory

My scenario is similar to the below sample.

```
[atlanta]
host1 http_port=80   maxRequestsPerChild=808
host2 http_port=303  maxRequestsPerChild=909
```

I have different hosts and each host has a specific value for the maxRequestsPerChild parameter.

If this is a static hosts file I could get the Value for maxRequestsPerChild  in each hosts.

But I need to pass the hosts and maxRequestsPerChild dynamically as a JSON. 
How to structure the JSON and access the same inside my playbook ?

Comment: Is it possible that I can give the above host info dynamically in an extra var option, a json preferably ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible doesn't directly support inventories under the form of JSON files.
However it fully supports *inventory scripts* returning JSON.

Here's the link to the official documentation, also describing the expected format of the output: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html

You'll probably want to implement the newer inventory format, whic is faster and explicitly allows per-host variables, as described in the section https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#tuning-the-external-inventory-script

In that case your script would return the following output:

```
    {
        "_meta": {
            "hostvars": {
                "host1": {
                    "http_port": 80,
                    "maxRequestsPerChild": 808
                },
                "host2": {
                    "http_port": 303,
                    "maxRequestsPerChild": 909
                }
            }
        },
        "atlanta": {
            "hosts": [ "host1", "host2" ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can we use them inside the playbook ? For eg. in my site.yml how can I use them ? I have a role which uses hosts and variable from that json. I am passing the json with -e "myjson.json"

Comment: "*Ansible doesn't directly support inventories under the form of JSON files.*" -- Why do you claim so?

Comment: If you don't want to use a group use `all` instread of `atlanta`.